# Error: InvalidDefinitionException - Cannot construct instance of FilterOperation, argument type mismatch in Jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am encountering an issue while trying to deserialize a JSON payload using Jackson in my Java application. The error message I'm receiving is:
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `rayanCommonLibrary.contracts.filterAndSort.FilterOperation`, problem: argument type mismatch
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 169] (through reference chain: rayanCommonLibrary.contracts.readContracts.ReadContract["Filters"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->rayanCommonLibrary.contracts.filterAndSort.Filter["Operation"])

I am running my project and I that error
this my code
I did not knew why happen because it was working and I did not change any thing

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum FilterOperation {
    IsEqualTo(1),
    IsNotEqualTo(2),
    IsGreaterThan(3),
    IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(4),
    IsLessThan(5),
    IsLessThanOrEqualTo(6),
    IsLike(7),
    IsNotLike(8),
    Contains(9),
    StartsWith(10),
    EndsWith(11),
    NotContains(12),
    IsNull(13),
    IsNotNull(14),
    IsContainedIn(15),
    IsNotContainedIn(16),
    And(17),
    Or(18),
    Not(19),
    OpenParenthesis(20),
    CloseParenthesis(21),
    IsExists(22);

    private static final Map<Integer, FilterOperation> lookup = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        int ordinal = 1;
        for (FilterOperation suit : EnumSet.allOf(FilterOperation.class)) {
            lookup.put(ordinal, suit);
            ordinal += 1;
        }
    }

    private final int manualValue;

    FilterOperation(int seconds) {
        this.manualValue = seconds;
    }

    int getManualValue() {
        return manualValue;
    }

    public static final int SIZE = java.lang.Integer.SIZE;

    public int getValue() {
        return this.ordinal();
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static FilterOperation forValue(int value) {
        return values()[value];
    }

    @JsonValue
    public Integer toValue() {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, FilterOperation> entry : lookup.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() == this)
                return entry.getKey();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```